# Querydsl and unexpected end of subtree

Tags: java, querydsl

It seems that that query is composed in the right way. `SomeId` exists.
However, I'm getting the following errors:

```
<AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree

Invalid path: 'Entity.id'

Invalid path: 'Entity.code'

left-hand operand of a binary operator was null
```

The query code(uses as subquery in another part):

```
JPAQueryFactory entityElementJPA = entityElementDAO.getJpaFactory();
        
    entityElementJPA
                        .select(QEntity.Entity.id)
                        .where(
                                QEntity.Entity.code.eq(
                                                entityElementJPA
                                                        .select(
                                                                QEntity.Entity.code)
                                                        .where(QEntity.Entity.id.eq(someId))
                                        )
                                        .and(QEntity.Entity.id.ne(someId))
                        );
```

I'm a newbie in java and querydsl, sorry if question is simple

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.from()` is missing, for JPAQueryFactory should be used